# How to scrape the img from the canvas which has zoomIn?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, canvas, request

I am trying to get the full res img with the best quality from a canvas,
here: [here](https://www.archiviodistato.firenze.it/archividigitali/riproduzione/?id=179684&ua=25)

what i am doing is :

```
# getting the image
base64_image = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('.openseadragon-  canvas canvas').toDataURL('image/png').substring(21);")

# decode the base64 image
output_image = base64.b64decode(base64_image)

# save to the output image
with open("image1.png", 'wb') as f:
   f.write(output_image)
```

what happens is that it saves part of the canvas (the zoomed in part).

I also looked at the traffic and the img is formed by calling  some api to get part of the img : `https://www.archiviodistato.firenze.it/archividigitali/?DeepZoom=tratte_libri_dell_eta/077/077 006 C 001 V.ptif_files/12/5_2.jpg`, I tried to do the same but I don't know how to combine the parts, so I prefer using selenium.

Here is the website:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5wVc.jpg)

Comment: https://www.archiviodistato.firenze.it/archividigitali/?DeepZoom=tratte_libri_dell_eta/077/077 006 C 001 V.ptif_files/12/5_2.jpg this link is not working

Comment: this is not the link, the link is : https://www.archiviodistato.firenze.it/archividigitali/riproduzione/?id=179684&ua=25

Comment: hmm even https://www.archiviodistato.firenze.it/archividigitali/riproduzione/?id=179684&ua=25 is not working at my end.

Comment: that's weird, it's working here,, i think it needs a vpn on your side I don't know